# PHP 2 class implements interface

Tags: php, class, interface

Why the code didn't display a solution to object Ab. If i want display for object Ab i must add $Ab->a().

```html
<?php

interface AB {

    public function a();
}

class A implements AB{

    public function a() {
        echo "aaaa";
    }

}

class B implements AB {

    public function a() {
        echo "bbbb";
    }

}

$Aa = new A;
$Ab = new B;
```

this code show only aaaa without bbbb. Why this work that? 
How to display both objects do nothing more?

Comment: `a` method __must be called__. And in your case it's just a __coincidence__ that class name `A` is same as method name `a` and therefore method `a` considered constructor and called implicitly.

Comment: also note: `Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; A has a deprecated constructor`

Comment: The first comment is right, what you're observing is just a happy accident because of the name of your function (PHP mistook it for a constructor, which is always executed when the class is instantiated). And as B001's comment points out, this feature is deprecated and will be removed in future anyway. If you gave the functions and classes meaningful names the situation probably wouldn't occur. In general, you must always call a function directly before it will output anything.

Comment: B001ᛦ  u_mulder  ADyson Thanks guys for help i get it now :) <3